# Acquisition data collection in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

Google analytics shows new users and returning users in the acquisition report. In GA documentation it is mentioned that if the user revisits the website with paid source/medium, the source and medium updates in the report. I have few doubts regarding this. If the user visits for the first time with the google search result and on the same day it returns but with a google ad link on the search result, will he be classified as new users or paid users or both in the acquisition report of that day? What will be his traffic source and medium? If it is classified as both then why all users count is equal to new users + returning users? Lastly, if the traffic data is updated can we find his first source, medium, and campaign in google analytics?

Answer (score 1):

In Google Analytics Universal:

Q: *If the user visits for the first time with the google search result and on the same day it returns but with a google ad link on the search result, will he be classified as new users or paid users or both in the acquisition report of that day?*

A: New user from `organic` and returning user from `paid`.

---

Q: *What will be his traffic source and medium?*

A: A session `google / organic` and a session `google / cpc`.

---

Q: *If it is classified as both then why all users count is equal to new users + returning users?*

A: It is **the same user** who generated **2 sessions**.

---

Q: *Lastly, if the traffic data is updated can we find his first source, medium, and campaign in google analytics?*

A: Yes, in `source / medium` there will be both the first and the second session.

---

In Google Analytics 4:

The change of source does not generate a new session.